# Can web browsers render embedded bitmaps from webfonts?

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser, fonts, webfonts

I've been referencing the findings [in this thread](https://typedrawers.com/discussion/1117/windows-doesnt-use-bitmaps-embedded-in-ttf-otf-fontforge) and [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43999875/prevent-anti-aliasing-or-sub-pixel-rendering-of-a-truetype-font) when trying to get a custom font that uses embedded bitmaps to render them via `@font-face`, and in my experimentation with fonts that I know are configured correctly, I found the following results displaying `日本語` using Windows 10 and Vivaldi (Chrome, etc), with ClearType on and configured (unsure if this matters):

```css
span {
  font-family: "SimSun"; // or just omitted, since this is a fallback font
}
```

[image: Defaulting to system font]

```css
@font-face { font-family: "font"; font-weight: normal; src: url('simsun_0.ttc'); }
span {
  font-family: "font";
}
```

[image: Explicitly declaring same font loaded with font-face]

`simsum_0.ttc` is the font that I pulled from `C:/Windows/Fonts/` and placed in the folder where the css lives. I've also verified that this file does indeed have embedded bitmaps and is configured correctly.

I've since just installed the font I'm working on and referenced it via its system name, which then loads the bitmaps correctly. Is there any way to get browsers to load the bitmaps from fonts loaded via `@font-face`? Is there any documentation or spec on this limitation, or possible work-arounds?

**More examples**

This works the same for custom-built fonts as well - here's an example with an .otf font in Chrome. The font loaded via it's name when installed on the system:

[image: Called via name]

and the same font loaded via `@font-face`'s `url`:

[image: Called via font-face]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome and Firefox (and likely others) run OTS on the fonts not available in the system, which removes the EBDT & EBLC tables (where the bitmaps are stored) from the font.

From the [OTS readme](https://github.com/khaledhosny/ots):

> The OpenType Sanitizer (OTS) parses and serializes OpenType files (OTF, TTF) and WOFF and WOFF2 font files, validating them and sanitizing them as it goes.
>
> The C library is integrated into Chromium and Firefox, and also simple command line tools to check files offline in a Terminal.
>
> The CSS font-face property is great for web typography. Having to use images in order to get the correct typeface is a great sadness; one should be able to use vectors.
>
> However, on many platforms the system-level TrueType font renderers have never been part of the attack surface before, and putting them on the front line is a scary proposition... Especially on platforms like Windows, where it's a closed-source blob running with high privilege.

In 2014, there was [interest in adding color bitmap tables to Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=324187), and [support was added to pass-through the color bitmap (CBDT & CBLC) tables to OTS](https://github.com/khaledhosny/ots/commit/27c50eb4a948bd921370beba5a98ad485e505444), so it seems possible that support could be added for these as well, if the browser requests it.

The steps I see to make this possible are:

1. Add the ability to pass-through the EBDT & EBLC tables to OTS. [This is the current location of the code that passes the color tables through](https://github.com/khaledhosny/ots/blob/master/src/ots.cc#L723).
2. Request that each project (Chromium, Firefox, etc) allow the pass-through.
3. Wait for all the updated code to be pushed down-stream.

There might be more complicated implementations of this sort of support (options in `@font-face`, etc), but this seems like the easiest, since the color tables are already supported (somewhat) in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `@font-face` doesn't support TrueType Collections (.ttc) files, so it will fail loading it. Does the console give you errors indicating something like this?

You could use a tool to extracy the needed .ttf from the .ttc file, if the license allows this. Or you could ask the foundry you got the font from to supply you with a .ttf (or .woff2, whatevr you need).

Comment: It works the same for .ttf files (and .otf), I'm afraid. I'm working on a custom font with embedded bitmaps where I have control over the format, so I'm not sure that's the issue (I think it actually loads the .ttc file ok) - I haven't seen any errors related to the embedded bitmaps, but I have seen others when I mess the opentype tables haha.

Comment: I added another example using the .otf I'm working on to the OP.

Comment: Any possibility of a demo we can look at?

Comment: Sure! The display page is here: https://jackhumbert.github.io/dreluhu/bitmaps.html - it loads the font from the web on the left, and the system font "Dreluhu Future" on the right. The font can be downloded here: https://github.com/jackhumbert/dreluhu/blob/master/future.otf

Comment: My assumption: it looks like it ignores the EBDT/EBLC tables when loaded through `@font-face`. I know CBDT/CBLC (color bitmap supprt) support is spotty, so maybe this is the same for single color bitmap glyphs. It would then fall back to the normal glyphs, with all subpixel rendering artifacts that come with it. Sorry I can't be of more help!

Comment: Ah gotcha - thanks! I'll see if I can dig deeper into OTS to see if this is an intended behavior/something they're willing to look into.

Answer (score -1):

A reliable and easy option is to use a service like FontSquirrel. 
https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Upload the fonts and it will generate everything you need so you can download, copy and paste into your project.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, but fontsquirrel's generator (even in expert mode) doesn't reference embedded bitmaps at all.

Comment: That's too bad @JackHumbert. Do you need all of the characters in the font, or just a few?

Comment: Yeah, it's a font in a custom unicode space, and the difference is pretty small: https://i.imgur.com/g9vLMuo.png (top is using the same font served from system fonts) - but it'd make a big difference in readability (this is specifically for chatting in Discord, where compactness and readability is important).

Comment: The difference is interesting on sloping sections of the characters. I was thinking that if you only needed a small number of characters you could try converting them to SVG first, but it doesn't sound like that would be a practical option. I hope you find a solution.